# Facebook sdk 3.0 at android another user cannot login

Tags: facebook

I'm making android application which is related with Facebook.

My application had succeed at logging on Facebook version 3.0 sdk.

However, the problem is that user who can log on this application is only me.
This means that nobody can log on my application.

How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Developer Settings` of your app at `Facebook`, change `Sandbox Mode` to `Off`